# Gatt - No output of the BLE UUID service value

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy, uuid, gatt

I have the problem that I don't get any output with my Java program of the temperature value of my SHT31 Smart Gadget.

Hardware used

- [SHT31 Smart Gadget Development Kit](https://www.sensirion.com/de/umweltsensoren/feuchtesensoren/development-kit/)
- [Smart Gadget Firware](https://github.com/Sensirion/SmartGadget-Firmware)

The UUID:

```
private static final UUID TEMPERATURE_UUID = UUID.fromString("00002235-b38d-4985-720e-0F993a68ee41");
```

My call

```
BluetoothDevice device = result.getDevice();
BluetoothGatt gatt = device.connectGatt(this, true, gattCallback);
BluetoothGattService tempOutput = gatt.getService(TEMPERATURE_UUID);
```

Result

```
null
```

What do I have to change to really output the temperature?

Comment: probably you want to discover services first

Comment: This is my output for the Device Address `D/BluetoothGatt: discoverServices() - device: E6:20:84:1E:BD:8C` and Service `D/BLEScannerActivity: discoverServices(): false`

Comment: did you discover services?

Comment: No services found yet. Search further :-)

Comment: did you call `gatt.discoverServices()`?

Comment: My call `boolean started = gatt.discoverServices();
        Log.d(TAG, "discoverServices(): " + started);`

Comment: ok, so it says that it failed to start service discovery. So when do you call `discoverServices()`?

Comment: First, I scan all available devices. I then connect to the desired device and check the service. This is the method: `private void info(ScanResult result) {
    BluetoothDevice device = result.getDevice();
    BluetoothGatt gatt = device.connectGatt(this, true, gattCallback);
    boolean started = gatt.discoverServices();
    Log.d(TAG, "discoverServices(): " + started);
}`

Comment: you need to call `discoverServices` after it connects to the device, in the `gattCallback`'s `onConnectionStateChange` method, when the `newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED`

Comment: So now I `get` true back as a result of `discoverServices`. But how can I access my temperature data now?

Comment: ok, now next step: you can start using service after the callback method `onServicesDiscovered` is called. So try calling `gatt.getService(TEMPERATURE_UUID);` inside `onServicesDiscovered`

Comment: In the method `onServicesDiscovered` I make a for loop over the `service`, `characteristic` and `desctriptor`. The output in the `descriptor` is `null`. My code: `for (BluetoothGattService service: gatt.getServices()) { for(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic : service.getCharacteristics()) { for(BluetoothGattDescriptor desctriptor: characteristic.getDescriptors()) {` . Also the query for `gatt.getService(TEMPERATURE_UUID)` results is `null`

Comment: `gatt.getService(TEMPERATURE_UUID) results is null` likely means that there is no such service in the device. Either you use wrong UUID, or the device does not work as expected

Comment: I've got another UUID for the temperature and now I get the following result `android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattService@b545dbe`. How do I get the temperature out of it now?

Comment: ok, looks better now. It means that the service is available. Now you have to get the characteristics from the service. Characteristics also has UUID, which you have to know. Or if there is only 1 characteristics - you can try using it.

Comment: With the following call `gatt.getService(TEMPERATURE_UUID).getCharacteristics());` I get the following result `[android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic@3405622, android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic@cef38b3]`. In the doc there is a temperature characteristic UUID. If I use this I get with following call `gatt.getService(TEMPERATURE_UUID).getCharacteristic(TEMPERATURE_UUID_CHARAC).getDescriptors().toString());` this result: `[android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattDescriptor@293de70, android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattDescriptor@15c05e9, android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattDescriptor@931b26e]`

Comment: How would I read out the temperature from the Characteristics now?

Answer (score 0):

I would start with the correct UUID. From the Documentation the UUID is

```
UUID.fromString("00002235-B38D-4985-720E-0F993A68EE41")
```

the UUID is case sensitive

Comment: Even fixing these errors with the wrong UUID does not give me the value of temperature